# update a document in mongoDB using JAVA

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

I'm just starting to learn mongoDB using JAVA. I have the the following document in mongo

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "513fa587c5d0cf174eb9b1f8"
},
"suitename": "test_suite_name",
"testname": "test_name]",
"milestones": [
    {
        "milestone_id": 45
    }
]
}
```

I have a compound key on suitename, testname, and milestone_id. I have to process a file which has these three fields. I create a simple DBObject query and check if count != 0

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
query.put("suitename", testsuite);
query.put("testname", testcase);
query.put("milestones.milestone_id", SampleProgram.milestone_id);
```

If count == 0 --> add document in mongo -> this seems to work fine

What I am trying to figure out is:
If I have a new value of milestone_id in my file, I just need to add a milestone to some existing document's milestone array. Existing document is determined based on suitename AND testname.

So if milestone_id = 10, the document should look like

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "513fa587c5d0cf174eb9b1f8"
},
"suitename": "test_suite_name",
"testname": "test_name]",
"milestones": [
    {
        "milestone_id": 45
    },
    {
        "milestone_id": 10
    }

]
}
```

How can I accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

This can be accomplished with the [$push](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/push/) operator which appends values to an array and the [update(…)](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html#update%28com.mongodb.DBObject,%20com.mongodb.DBObject%29) method.

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
query.put("suitename", testsuite);
query.put("testname", testcase);

BasicDBObject push = new BasicDBObject();
push.put("$push",
  new BasicDBObject("milestones",
    new BasicDBObject("milestone_id", SampleProgram.milestone_id)));

yourCollection.update(query, push);
```

Comment: Works great. Can you tell me where you got the API reference for put?

Comment: @user2162796 I have the feeling too that the MongoDB page is structured somehow weirdly, but you can find the API docs for the various versions for Java [here](http://api.mongodb.org/java/index.html). All the info can be found in the appropriate "language centers"... (I can't exactly express why I'm frustrated by the structure of the page, but I fell like struggling each time I need something...)

Comment: @user2162796: Since I knew the right term I just googled for it.

Answer (score 1):

```
BasicDBObject newDocument = new BasicDBObject();
newDocument.append("$set", new BasicDBObject().append("clients", 110));

BasicDBObject searchQuery = new BasicDBObject().append("hosting", "hostB");

collection.update(searchQuery, newDocument);
```

Comment: You should explain the answer as well